# How install the latest FileZilla from its official site?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

How can I install the latest  FileZilla from its official [site](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client)?

I can find FileZilla from my software centre and install it. But it is version 3.24.0. While the latest is 3.25.2.

Can I upgrade the version 3.24.0 that I have already installed to 3.25.2?

I always wonder how to install from its official site, but it is not a .deb. It looks like the source files of FileZilla that you need to compile or build. But how can I do it?

Any ideas?

This is from the site but it is just not very helpful to me:

> Installing on GNU/Linux and other Unix(-like) systems
>
> It is recommended that you use the package manager of your
>   distribution. If you're using GNU/Linux, you can also try using the
>   precompiled binaries. After extracting the files to any location
>   (location does not matter, FileZilla can detect its own installation
>   prefix), you can start the program using the filezilla executable in
>   the bin/ subdirectory. Please note that due to differences in
>   distributions, the provided binaries might not work on your system.
>   Alternatively you can also compile FileZilla from source.

Comment: as far as I can tell from the tar file: it is already compiled so extract it into /opt/ and add the bin path to your path

Comment: @Rinzwind how can I `add the bin path to my path`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=add+path ;)

Comment: If Filezilla is only for your own use, then create a `bin` directory in your /home folder, drop the extracted Filezilla folder into ~/bin, and ~/bin is already in your path, so you should be able to run Filezilla from the command line.

Comment: @heynnema do i have removed the existing FileZilla that I have already installed? Also how can I run Filezilla from the command line - what  command line should I use?

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Filezilla is only for your own use, then create a bin directory in your /home folder, drop the extracted Filezilla folder into ~/bin, and ~/bin is already in your path, so you should be able to run Filezilla from the command line.

Structure like so:

```
/home
  /your_username (your home directory)
    /bin (folder)
    symlink to Filezilla/bin/filezilla (symlink)
       /Filezilla (folder)
         /bin (folder)
           filezilla (executable file)
```

You don't **have** to deinstall the older version, but it's a good idea.

To run from the command line, if you've created the structure, and the symlink correctly, you should just be able to type `Filezilla`.